# Type: ParseError Message: syntax error, unexpected '$data' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')' line number ; 68 Code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter, constructor

i dont no why, but my __contsruct is not working (running)

my controller like this :

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('M_jenis');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('url');

}

public function ubah($id_jenis)
{
    $this->load->model('M_Jenis');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $data['judul'] = 'Ubah Jenis';
    $data['C_Jenis'] = $this->M_Jenis->getJenisById($id_jenis);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_jenis', 'Id Jenis', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama_jenis', 'Nama Jenis', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->model('M_Jenis');
        $this->load->view('template_admin/v_header_admin', $data);
        $this->load->view('data_jenis/v_jenis_ubah'$data);
        $this->load->view('template_admin/v_footer_admin');
    } else {
       $this->M_Jenis->ubahDataJenis();
       $this->session->set_flashdata('Data Jenis','Diubah');
       redirect('C_Jenis');
    }

}
```

}

my model like this

```
public function getJenisById($id_jenis)
{
    return $this->db->get_where('tb_input_jenis',['id_jenis'=>$id_jenis])->row_array();
}
```

i dont know why, but i think my construct is not working, can you both help me ? :(

Comment: which PHP and CI version you are using?

Comment: Your title and post seem to disagree. Is the issue a syntax error, or that your constructor does not have the behavior your expect?

Answer (score 0):

You missed a comma at the following line:

```
$this->load->view('data_jenis/v_jenis_ubah'$data);
```

Add a comma before the $data var and the line should look like:

```
$this->load->view('data_jenis/v_jenis_ubah', $data);
```

I hope it solves the problem.